# Gettext : How to update po and pot files after the source is modified

Tags: python, gettext, xgettext

I've got a python project with internationalized strings.
I've modified the source codes and the lines of the strings are changed, i.e. in pot and po files lines of he strings are not pointing to correct lines.

So how to update the po and pot files to new string locations in files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could have a look to [this script](http://www.lxg.de/code/playing-with-xgettext) to update your po files with new code. It use [xgettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/xgettext-Invocation.html) and [msgmerge](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/msgmerge-Invocation.html).

```
echo '' > messages.po # xgettext needs that file, and we need it empty
find . -type f -iname "*.py" | xgettext -j -f - # this modifies messages.po
msgmerge -N existing.po messages.po > new.po
mv new.po existing.po
rm messages.po
```

Comment: This is great that you combine the two commands I need into one. +1

Comment: @Manu : There is a [gettext for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Using `autoconf` and `automake` you can simply change into the `po` subdirectory and run:

```
make update-po
```

or:

```
make update-gmo
```

As a package maintainer we would typically change into the `build/po` directory and run `update-po`. This updates the `.po` files in the source tree (assuming an out-of-tree or `VPATH` build). The updated `.po` files are then committed into the repository and after this command a new commit needs to be prepared.

The `update-gmo` call produces the `.gmo` files that are normally not committed into the repository, this is usually done automatically during a build.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use meson:

`<project_id>-pot` and `<project_id>-update-po`.

E.g. for [iputils](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/) project:

```
$ dir="/tmp/build"
$ meson . $dir && ninja iputils-pot -C $dir && ninja iputils-update-po -C $dir
```

SOURCE: https://mesonbuild.com/i18n-module.html